# How can I use pivot to find the records with the most columns populated?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, case

I have a problem where I have 5 columns.

[image]

What I want to do is add a count on the end with the number of columns where there is no null value.

I am trying to use pivot as this seems to be the most logical SQL clause. Any ideas on this? I haven't used Pivot in many instances so this is new for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inline pivot/conditional aggregate and a `COUNT` seems to be what you want here. As all your columns have different data types, you need to also use some `CASE` expressions. Something like this:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       a,
       ...
       (SELECT COUNT(V.C)
        FROM (VALUES(CASE WHEN a IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END),
                    (CASE WHEN b IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END),
                    (CASE WHEN c IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END),
                    (CASE WHEN d IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END),
                    (CASE WHEN e IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END),
                    (CASE WHEN f IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END))V(C)) AS NonNullColumns
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: I don't understand the V(c) alias. When I run this in fiddle I'm getting some syntax errors. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=edd50b9e945421a3f7daaa3598c674c7

Comment: `f` should be `f,` @Axwack . Columns in a query need to be comma delimited. If you fix the typographical error you introduced, the query works fine: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d0f488ce66dc16d6ff07e9715717eab0)